# Formatting NSString for superscript and subscript

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, subscript, superscript

I am writing a utility app for some coworkers. The app is essentially a custom notepad, with buttons that represent the shorthand they use to transcribe a task. All of the buttons add a string to arrays that I have set up to hold the transcript, and I add the strings to the row arrays like this.

```
[currentRow addObject:@"("];
```

Some of the shorthand needs to be written in subscript, and some in superscript. There are not Unicode characters for all of the characters that I need, so I have been trying to sort through the code around Attributed Strings,but I'm not quite getting it. Does anyone have advice on this or some sample code?

Also, after this transcript is printed to the screen during transcription, I send it to an email message body.. so I assume I'll need to worry about formatting there as well. I am currently using plain text, but the email could be HTML. Thanks!

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555735/how-to-make-subscripts-and-superscripts-using-nsattributedstring)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a subscript with NSAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194860/how-to-create-a-subscript-with-nsattributedstring)

Comment: I am still not sure how to implement kCTSuperscriptAttributeName inside NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you display the text in a WebView you can use html tags to set superscript. It also has the advantage to run on older iOS versions and you can reuse the text in your mail.

```
NSString *myText=@"This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup> text.";
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:myText baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Sten. While that doesn't actually answer my question about attributes for an UITextView, its exactly what I am going to use for this app. I hadn't used UIWebView yet, but it was really easy to implement. I tested it in my app, and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for the tip!

Comment: Just to add some more information. I am using a webview to display my text with super and subscripts, but I then wanted to also have a simple notepad for my users. Of course putting plain text and HTML text into the email body would only work for one or the other. I solved the problem by adding the following. `code`                                                            NSString *nonHTMLText = [[NSString stringWithString:notesTextView.text] init];
    NSString *htmlText = [nonHTMLText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />"];`code`