# Can I have similar to UILabel Truncate Text on UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can I have UILabel truncate text similar functionality on UIWebview?

So I want to truncate the text on tail, for example

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890

becomes

> abcdefghijkl...

My UIWebview will only have one line.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by adding some CSS to the web content (for example this CSS from [Truncate String with Ellipsis](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)).

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Otherwise, why not use a `UILabel` with an `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Does NSAttributedString support html tag, for example <sub>? Because I have it in my string.

Comment: There is not support for actual HTML-tags (except on OSX where you can use initWithHTML:) but you can do all the formatting, even [subscript and superscript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2195008/608157) on iOS. There is also some open source code available that deal with HTML parsing to attributed strings on iOS if you really need it.

Comment: I have tried with OHAttributedLabel but it doesn't work and I just figured out it doesn't support it :(

Comment: What version are you targeting? The native UILabel supports attributed strings since iOS 6.